# Copy NumPy matrix into NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am using `cvxpy` to solve an optimization problem. I want to store the output, a `matrix` into a `ndarray`.

This is the reduced test case. `a` representing the returned value from `cvxpy`.

```
import numpy as np

z = np.zeros((3,7))
a = np.matrix("[1; 2; 3]")
z[0, 0] = a[0]
z[1, 0] = a[1]
z[2, 0] = a[2]
```

I would like to replace the last three lines with something better, but everything I try results in an error. E.g.,

```
>>> z[:, 0] = a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
>>> np.copyto(z[:, 0], a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1) into shape (3)
```

I would appreciate a little help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to use a list of the column index for indexing into `z` and then simply assign the NumPy matrix `a` there -

```
z[:,[0]] = a
```

Another way would be to use the transpose of the matrix `a`, which would be a row vector to assign into the sliced version of the first column in `z` -

```
z[:,0] = a.T
```

Comment: `a.A1` might work here.  I.e. convert the 2d matrix into  a 1d array.

Comment: @hpaulj You love that `.A1` thing, don't you? :)

Comment: @hpaulj I didn't know about `a.A1`, such a nice syntactic sugar :P