# Broadcasting numpy matrices using arrays of indices

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have these numpy objects:

```
>>> x = np.matrix([[1],[2],[3]])
>>> i = ([1,2],0)
>>> y = np.matrix([[4],[5]])
```

When I do `x[i]` I get as I expect:

```
>>> x[i]
matrix([[2],
        [3]])
```

However, when I try to assign to `x[i]`, I get funky behavior:

```
>>> x[i] = y
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
>>> y.shape
(2, 1)
>>> x[i].shape
(2, 1)
```

I have figured out some workarounds, but they're workarounds and not what I want:

```
>>> x[1:,0] = y
>>> x
matrix([[1],
        [4],
        [5]])
>>> x = np.array([[1],[2],[3]]); y = np.array(y)
>>> x[i] = y[:,0]
>>> x
array([[1],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

The second workaround is not acceptable because `y` could have a more general shape than a column vector.

Comment: Why are you using `numpy.matrix`?

Comment: Because I need to do matrix multiplication. np.matrix offers an easy way to do that. Also, as the second workaround demonstrates, converting to np.array does not offer a straightforward solution.

Comment: The convenience of `*` over `.dot()` isn't worth all the headaches of `numpy.matrix`. The class literally only exists to make it easier to teach people who would be unable to learn to use NumPy without the close correspondence between mathematical and programming syntax, and even then, `numpy.array` and `@` are a better option these days.

Comment: @user2357112 Just for curiosity: what is `@` in this context? Are you referring to decorators? If so, what is the relation with OP's question?

Comment: @iled: [It's the matrix multiplication operator.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/)

Comment: @user2357112 Right, thank you. I was reading from review and didn't notice the other answers below.

Comment: @user2357112 I changed my code over to np.array and so far it seems to work fine. I had to put in some conditionals to handle broadcasting edge cases but it wasn't that bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `numpy.matrix`. It's terrible. It causes so many weird incompatibilities and has so many inconsistencies, including this one.

Use `numpy.array`. With arrays, `x[i]` is one-dimensional, and assigning a one-dimensional `y` of equal shape to `x[i]` will work fine.

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([[1], [2], [3]])
y = numpy.array([4, 5])
i = ([1, 2], 0)

print(x[i].shape)
print(y.shape)

x[i] = y

print(repr(x))
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/6q68oJ):

```
(2,)
(2,)
array([[1],
       [4],
       [5]])
```

If you want to do matrix multiplication, use the `@` operator, or the `dot` method if you're on too old a Python version or too old a NumPy version to have `@`.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing with a simpe `[1,2]` works:

```
In [71]: x
Out[71]: 
matrix([[1],
        [2],
        [3]])
In [72]: y
Out[72]: 
matrix([[4],
        [5]])
In [73]: x[[1,2],:]
Out[73]: 
matrix([[2],
        [3]])
In [74]: x[[1,2],:] = y
```

Trying to use a tuple has problems:

```
In [78]: i = ([1,2],0)
In [79]: x[i] = y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-699d63749224> in <module>()
----> 1 x[i] = y

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,1) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

Changing `i` to `i = ([1,2],slice(None))` matches my first case.

Using `0` instead of `:'` is also a problem:

```
In [82]: x[[1,2],0] = y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-8b683eb93954> in <module>()
----> 1 x[[1,2],0] = y

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,1) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

I suspect it is trying to do the assgnment to a `(2,)` as a `numpy` array, before converting the results back to matrix.

It's trying to the equivalent of:

```
In [83]: x.A[[1,2],0] = y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-b2ccc78af912> in <module>()
----> 1 x.A[[1,2],0] = y

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,1) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,)
```

where as it needs a flattened version of `y`:

```
In [84]: x.A[[1,2],0] = y.A1    # max `y` a 1d array
x[[1,2],0] = y.A1       # also works
```

Earlier today there was a similar problem: [Copy NumPy matrix into NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043851/copy-numpy-matrix-into-numpy-array)

The convenience of using `*` for matrix multiplication rarely outweighs the clumkiness of restricting dimensions to 2.  `np.dot` works just as well.  And arrays also provide `tensordot`, `einsum` and `matmul` (and the `@` operator).

`np.matrix` is a subclass of `np.ndarray`.  It inherits methods.  Often it performs the action with the `ndarray` method, and cleans up the dimesions, either forcing 1d results to 2d, or scalars.

Here's the code for the `*` matrix multiplication:

```
Signature: x.__mul__(other)
Source:   
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
            # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
            return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
        if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
            return N.dot(self, other)
        return NotImplemented
```